# R - how to split into terciles during group_by

Tags: r

Let's say we want to calculate the means of sepal length based on tercile groups of sepal width.

We can use the `split_quantile` function from the `fabricatr` package and do the following:

```
iris %>% 
    group_by(split_quantile(Sepal.Width, 3)) %>% 
    summarise(Sepal.Length = mean(Sepal.Length))
```

So far so good. Now, let's say we want to `group_by(Species, split_quantile(Sepal.Width, 3))` instead of just `group_by(split_quantile(Sepal.Width, 3))`.

However, what if we want the terciles to be calculated ***inside*** of the each species type and not generally?

Basically, what I'm looking for could be achieved by splitting `iris` into several dataframes based on `Species`, using `split_quantile` on those dataframes to calculate terciles and then joining the dataframes back together. However, I'm looking for a way to do this ***without*** splitting the dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You kinda have written the answer in your text, but you can create a new variable for tercile after grouping by species, then regroup with both `Species` and `Tercile`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(fabricatr)
iris %>% 
    group_by(Species) %>%
    mutate(Tercile = split_quantile(Sepal.Width, 3)) %>%
    group_by(Species, Tercile) %>%
    summarise(Sepal.Length = mean(Sepal.Length))
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#> # Groups:   Species [3]
#>   Species    Tercile Sepal.Length
#>   <fct>      <fct>          <dbl>
#> 1 setosa     1               4.69
#> 2 setosa     2               5.08
#> 3 setosa     3               5.27
#> 4 versicolor 1               5.61
#> 5 versicolor 2               6.12
#> 6 versicolor 3               6.22
#> 7 virginica  1               6.29
#> 8 virginica  2               6.73
#> 9 virginica  3               6.81
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks - I thought `group_by` works only in combination with `summarise` and I didn't know that if we use `split_quantile` in `mutate` after `group_by` the grouping will be applied.